# How can I make every new Group a type Mailing List?

Tags: extension, groups, hooks, mailing

I have a request to enable making every new Group created (using search results -> Actions -> Add Contacts to Group) a group type Mailing List by default, thereby saving a user having to check the box next to Mailing List.  Can I do that with a new extension, using one of these [hooks?](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Hook+Reference)

Answer (score 4):

Use [hook_civicrm_pre](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_pre) to modify the group-to-be prior to saving in the database.  Experiment a little with your hook function, adding the debug lines:

```
if ($op == 'create' && $objectName == 'Group') {
  print_r($params);
  die();
}
```

Try creating a group with the Mailing List checked and then creating a group with it not checked to see what it passes.  Write your code so that the $params array on a group where Mailing List is not checked ends up looking like the case where it is checked.  And obviously delete your debug!

Comment: Oh, and publish the extension when you're done.  I bet many people would like it.  (Though you do need to be careful about access control groups also being mailing list groups--people can unsubscribe themselves out of permissions!)